# number of strings made of 0 and 1 with no adjacent 1

Tags: combinatorics

I have a word of $n-k$ 0s. How many ways are there are to put $k$ 1 in a way that no two 1 are adjacent?

My manual says that there are $n-k+1$ free spaces. I don't understand why there is the $+1$. If the words are made by $n$ elements with $k$ 1, I understand that there are $n-k$ zeros, if you add up the 1 you get a string of $n$ elements, so why the additional space?

A bit of background about this issue. Here we are trying to calulcate the number of subsets of $k$ elements that can be made out of a subset of naturals of cardinality $n$, with no adjacent natural numbers; A topic connected with the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Don't forget, you can put $1's$ before the first $0$ or after the final $0$.  I suggest writing it out for small values of $n,k$.

Answer (score 1):

First keep the $n-k$ zeroes in a row.Suppose $n-k=2 $.Then there are$ 3 $spaces-one to left of the first $0$,one in the centre and one in extreme right. That accounts for the $+1$.Now choose $k$ spaces for the $1's$ from $n-k+1$ options.